# Fatal error: Class "mysqli_connect" not found?

Tags: php

The below code tells about connecting with database 'db' but mysqli_connect() doesnt seem to work kindly help

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db";
    
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    //check connection
    if($conn -> connect_error){
        die("connection failed".$conn -> connect_error);
    }
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: [`mysqli_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) is a method and not a class,  you need to use [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) for the oo version.

Comment: ok but what should i do to use mysqli for the oo version

Comment: Have you tried just replacing the existing call with `mysqli`?